# Is there a way to track a single rule violation in Sonar time machine?

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

I have created a regex checkstyle rule. I would like to track the violations for this rule separately in time machine. While I can see options to track 'info violations' and so on, I couldn't find a widget where I can just enter the rule key and track its violations over time. Is it possible to do this with Sonar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do confirm that this is not possible to track the evolution of the number of violations on a given rule over time. I've created a JIRA ticket to cover this use case : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4389

Comment: Thanks for confirmation and creating the JIRA ticket.